# Android usar findViewById de outra activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Preciso atribuir um valor para um elemento que está em outra activity

estou tentando dessa forma:

```
MainActivity activityprincipal = new MainActivity();

WebView view = (WebView) activityprincipal.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Comment: Isso não pode ser feito assim. Explique o que quer conseguir com isso.

Comment: eu tenho uma classe, nessa classe eu quero passar um loadurl no webview, mas este webview esta em outra activity, como eu posso fazer isso

Comment: Porque você não salva o loadurl ou o objeto webview e passa no bundle pra outra activity por Intent?

Comment: como fazer isto ? eu não muitos sobre android/java

Comment: Você quer passar um valor de uma activity B para uma activity A (sendo que a Activity A é a "primeira" e a Activity B é chamada pela A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dito pela [@GiulianaBezerra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54222/giuliana-bezerra) no comentário, usa se um [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) para fornecer vínculos entre as Activity's em tempo de execução.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_URL = "MainActivity.URL";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void startActivity(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        // Adiconamos a url ao intent...
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, url);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Na outra Activity, pegamos o valor :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_URL);

  WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
 view.loadUrl(url);

}
```

[FONTE](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: pelo oque vi vc esta passando a url da activity um para um webview na activity 2 é isso ?

Comment: huum no meu caso tem que ser ao contrario, acho que vai ajudar vou tentar

Comment: no EXTRA_URL esta dando cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @JeffersonMelloOlynyki Se é ao contrário use startActivityForResult(), na Activity que tem a webView para chamar a outra Activity, e implemente o método  onActivityResult(). Veja [Como obter resultados de uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: oque seria o Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class); 

OtherActivity , a classe atual ou a que vai receber a url

Comment: consegui aqui, obrigado